# Arguments (route, from, next) types within route guard vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I export a function, which I pass to `router.beforeEach`:

```
export default function (route, from, next) {
  log.debug(route.path)

  if (!identity.state.authenticated) {
    log.debug('redirecting to "login" view...')
    next({ name: 'login' })
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

But this causes 3 TypeScript errors:

> ```
> TS7006: Parameter 'route' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> TS7006: Parameter 'from' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> TS7006: Parameter 'next' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> ```

What types would be best for those? I can make them just objects, but aren't there some types to import from `vue`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`router.beforeEach` is [typed as](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/master/src/router.ts#L274):

```js
beforeEach(guard: NavigationGuardWithThis<undefined>): () => void
```

and `NavigationGuardWithThis` is [typed as](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/722ee9d4c5f0380f9ae2b3f9a2e715f764b2b55e/src/types/index.ts#L409):

```js
export interface NavigationGuardWithThis<T> {
  (
    this: T,
    to: RouteLocationNormalized,
    from: RouteLocationNormalized,
    next: NavigationGuardNext
  ): NavigationGuardReturn | Promise<NavigationGuardReturn>
}
```

So you need these types to import from `vue-router`:

- [`RouteLocationNormalized`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/722ee9d4c5f0380f9ae2b3f9a2e715f764b2b55e/src/types/index.ts#L175)
- [`NavigationGuardNext`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/722ee9d4c5f0380f9ae2b3f9a2e715f764b2b55e/src/types/index.ts#L369)
- *I'm not sure how how to import [`NavigationGuardReturn`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/722ee9d4c5f0380f9ae2b3f9a2e715f764b2b55e/src/types/index.ts#L386), but since it [includes `void`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/722ee9d4c5f0380f9ae2b3f9a2e715f764b2b55e/src/types/index.ts#L387), omitting the return is also acceptable in TypeScript.*

```js
import { RouteLocationNormalized, NavigationGuardNext } from 'vue-router'

export default function(
  to: RouteLocationNormalized,
  from: RouteLocationNormalized,
  next: NavigationGuardNext
) {
  /*...*/
}
```